# Get the row index or _id in select sql query

Tags: postgresql

Help me on this. I have a table without any id ok pk, those created manually or sequentially.

```
|   some_ts   |message|...|
|'2022-12-01' |'error'|...|
...
```

So, I could have a million of records here and I need select rows with some eligibility conditions to process them to an API and then updates those rows into the table with the API response. Having in mind that it's impossible to load a so considerably amount of data in memory to process them, I was thinking on something like a chunk. But I'm stuck here.
For example, I'm thinking in query the table in a loop like:

```
offset_q := 1
limit_q := 500

for {
  query := fmt.Sprintf("select last_index, * from table where some_ts > now() - interval '2 days' offset %d limit %d", offset_q, limit_q)
  rows, err := db.Execute(query)
  if err == sql.ErrNoRows {return}
  ...
  // here request to API and update loaded in memory data
  // then update table 

  //???
  // last id or row index from the select
  offset_q = last_index + 1
}
```

I'm working in Golang, sorry if the example doesn't help you much, but there is the idea. What I need is if it's possible to get such information from postgres, some last row index in the query result or anything I can continue triggering the table from the last record retrieved to the next 500

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
index_page := 0
limit_q := 500

for {
  offset_q = index_page * limit_q; 

  query := fmt.Sprintf("select last_index, * from table where some_ts > now() - interval '2 days' offset %d limit %d", offset_q, limit_q)
  rows, err := db.Execute(query)
  if err == sql.ErrNoRows {return}
  ...
  // here request to API and update loaded in memory data
  // then update table 

  // increasing page index
  index_page = index_page + 1
}
```

your offset and limit will be like this:

```
offset 0    limit 500
offset 500  limit 500
offset 1000 limit 500
offset 1500 limit 500
offset 2000 limit 500
offset 2500 limit 500
```